# Python Dataframe Store name of the column with row max

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has mulitple columns. I find max value in each row. Now I want to know the which column is max in each row and I want to store it. Finally, I would like to know how many times this row was max (top), etc.
My code:

```
df= 
    Aple  Bana  Oran
0    10   20   30
1    2    5    1  
2    8    9    4
3    45   21   18  
cols = df.columns.tolist
df['max_val'] = df[cols].max(axis=1)
df['max_col'] = df[df[cols]==df['max']] # store name of max value
```

Present output:
Above `df['max_val']` produced the desired output. The problem is with the `df['max_col']`. It failed to produced desired output

Expected output:

```
df= 
    Aple  Bana  Oran  max_val max_col
0    10   20   30     30      Oran
1    2    5    1      5       Bana 
2    8    9    4      9       Bana
3    45   21   18     45      Aple

print(df['max_col'].value_counts())
Bana 2
Oran 1
Aple 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `idxmax`:

```
df['max_val'], df['max_col'] = df.max(axis=1), df.idxmax(axis=1)

# also
df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Aple  Bana  Oran  max_val max_col
0    10    20    30       30    Oran
1     2     5     1        5    Bana
2     8     9     4        9    Bana
3    45    21    18       45    Aple
```